# How to use CMake FetchContent to link OpenSSL?

Tags: cmake, openssl

I don't quite understand how to integrate libraries by FetchContent if they were not found by find_package.

Currently, I have the following code:

```
# OpenSSL dependency
option(USE_SYSTEM_OPENSSL "Use preinstalled OpenSSL" ON)

# configure OpenSSL
if(USE_SYSTEM_OPENSSL)
    find_package(OpenSSL COMPONENTS Crypto SSL)
endif()
if(NOT USE_SYSTEM_OPENSSL OR NOT OPENSSL_FOUND)
    # get dependencies from net
    include(FetchContent)

    message(STATUS "Not using system OpenSSL, using built-in OpenSSL project instead.")
    FetchContent_Declare(
        OpenSSL
            GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/openssl/openssl
            GIT_TAG        master
            USES_TERMINAL_DOWNLOAD TRUE)
    FetchContent_MakeAvailable(OpenSSL)

    # (1) ...

endif()

#(2)
target_link_libraries(target OpenSSL::SSL OpenSSL::Crypto)
```

What should I write at (1) for (2) to work?

Comment: OpenSSL is not a CMake project. (at least, the project on https://github.com/openssl/openssl cannot be built with CMake). You cannot use `FetchContent` for it. You may, however use ExternalProject for build OpenSSL. BTW, with your current code you would get an error at line `FetchContent_MakeAvailable(OpenSSL)`. Obviously, content of `(1)` and `(2)` cannot resolve this error since they are come **after** the erroneous line.

Comment: Thanks! So `FetchContent` can only build CMake projects? Are there any other requirements (because I need to do the same thing with Boost too)?

Comment: And why `find_package` work for OpenSSL if it's not a CMake project?

Comment: There is the script [FindOpenSSL.cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindOpenSSL.html), which helps CMake projects to locate OpenSSL. This script is shipped with CMake. `FetchContent` module eventually calls `add_subdirectory` with the top-level directory of the subproject. If a subproject is not ready for such inclusion, then this inclusion will fail. Most projects doesn't describe the ability of being included as a subproject, but this could work. Just give a try.

Comment: Would you kindly describe how do I link Boost (Asio and Beast) with `FetchContent`? The problem is the same as with OpenSSL: I need to unify linking if the package is found and if not.

Comment: For Boost you could try the same approach as you do for OpenSSL. If CMake would warn about missed ``Boost::asio`` imported target, then actual target is names as `asio`, and you need to create an alias for it: `add_library(Boost::asio ALIAS asio)`.

Comment: Don't you wanna create an answer for this question with that exact info so I can like it and close the question?

Comment: For what purpose you want an answer? For OpenSSL, as stated in the question post? - The answer would be "no, you cannot do that". For Boost? - But the question post is not about the Boost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `FetchContent_Declare`, you must use [`ExternalProject_Add`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html):

```
set(OPENSSL_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/openssl-src) # default path by CMake
set(OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/openssl)
set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/include)
set(OPENSSL_CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${OPENSSL_SOURCE_DIR}/config)
ExternalProject_Add(
  OpenSSL
  SOURCE_DIR ${OPENSSL_SOURCE_DIR}
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git
  GIT_TAG OpenSSL_1_1_1n
  USES_TERMINAL_DOWNLOAD TRUE
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND
    ${OPENSSL_CONFIGURE_COMMAND}
    --prefix=${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}
    --openssldir=${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}
  BUILD_COMMAND make
  TEST_COMMAND ""
  INSTALL_COMMAND make install
  INSTALL_DIR ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}
)
```

After doing that, you cannot include or link it with your other targets yet. To do that, you still need to declare the library, as if it was found using `find_package`, *i.e.* as if [`FindOpenSSL.cmake`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindOpenSSL.html) was used:

```
# We cannot use find_library because ExternalProject_Add() is performed at build time.
# And to please the property INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES,
# we make the include directory in advance.
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_library(OpenSSL::SSL STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_property(TARGET OpenSSL::SSL PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libssl.${OPENSSL_LIBRARY_SUFFIX})
set_property(TARGET OpenSSL::SSL PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_dependencies(OpenSSL::SSL OpenSSL)

add_library(OpenSSL::Crypto STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_property(TARGET OpenSSL::Crypto PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libcrypto.${OPENSSL_LIBRARY_SUFFIX})
set_property(TARGET OpenSSL::Crypto PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_dependencies(OpenSSL::Crypto OpenSSL)
```

Now you can include the OpenSSL and link with it normally.