# OpenSSL Dependency with FetchContent in a cross-compile toolchain

Tags: cmake

I'm cross-compiling for a raspberry pi. I want to use [rabbitmq-c](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c), which depends on OpenSSL. I'd like for CMake to compile all of the dependencies for me since it's already setup to build stuff for the pi.

I'm trying to include both projects with FetchContent

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)

project(
  proj
  LANGUAGES CXX
)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH .)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(openssl
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git
  GIT_TAG openssl-3.1.1
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(openssl)

FetchContent_Declare(rabbitmq-c
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c.git
  GIT_TAG v0.13.0
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(rabbitmq-c)
```

But, when trying to configure the project, rabbitmq-c can't find OpenSSL:

```
...
-- Looking for posix_spawnp in rt - not found
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.26.4/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
  system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY
  OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is at least version "1.1.1")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.26.4/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.26.4/share/cmake/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:670 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  build/_deps/rabbitmq-c-src/CMakeLists.txt:116 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I assume this is because openssl does not get compiled and installed until `make` is run, so when `rabbitmq-c` looks for this package the necessary cmake files are not found. How can I chain dependencies together like this?

**Edit**:

After @starball's comment, I moved to ExternalProject:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)

project(
  proj
  LANGUAGES CXX
)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH .)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

include(FetchContent)
include(ExternalProject)

###########
# OpenSSL
set(OPENSSL_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/openssl-src) # default path by CMake
set(OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/openssl)
set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/include)
set(OPENSSL_CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${OPENSSL_SOURCE_DIR}/config)
ExternalProject_Add(
  OpenSSL
  SOURCE_DIR ${OPENSSL_SOURCE_DIR}
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git
  GIT_TAG openssl-3.1.1
  USES_TERMINAL_DOWNLOAD TRUE
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND
    ${OPENSSL_CONFIGURE_COMMAND}
    --prefix=${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}
    --openssldir=${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}
  BUILD_COMMAND make
  TEST_COMMAND ""
  INSTALL_COMMAND make install
  INSTALL_DIR ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}
)

# We cannot use find_library because ExternalProject_Add() is performed at build time.
# And to please the property INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES,
# we make the include directory in advance.
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_library(OpenSSL::SSL STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_property(TARGET OpenSSL::SSL PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libssl.${OPENSSL_LIBRARY_SUFFIX})
set_property(TARGET OpenSSL::SSL PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_dependencies(OpenSSL::SSL OpenSSL)

add_library(OpenSSL::Crypto STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_property(TARGET OpenSSL::Crypto PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libcrypto.${OPENSSL_LIBRARY_SUFFIX})
set_property(TARGET OpenSSL::Crypto PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_dependencies(OpenSSL::Crypto OpenSSL)

set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR})

###########
# RabbitMQ
FetchContent_Declare(rabbitmq-c
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c.git
  GIT_TAG v0.13.0
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(rabbitmq-c)
```

and I still get the same error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.26.4/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
  system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY)
  (Required is at least version "1.1.1")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.26.4/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.26.4/share/cmake/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:670 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  build/_deps/rabbitmq-c-src/CMakeLists.txt:116 (find_package)
```

Comment: note: all `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` should go after all `FetchContent_MakeAvailable`. (Read the docs for the reason why)

Comment: hm. Theoretically, I think this should be working. see the [find_package docs' section on Config mode search procedure](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#config-mode-search-procedure), which states that config search mode will start by looking for a config package file in [`CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_REDIRECTS_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_REDIRECTS_DIR.html).

Comment: oh wait. nvm. OpenSSL doesn't seem to have builtin CMake support.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use CMake FetchContent to link OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66829315/how-to-use-cmake-fetchcontent-to-link-openssl) (top search result of googling "`openssl fetchcontent`")

Comment: @starball, sadly, no. I still get the same error

Comment: if you're trying to sidestep find_package(OpenSSL), then you need to set `OpenSSL_FOUND` to a truthy value.